# Which eos block explorers have an API endpoint to query accounts?

Tags: api, javascript, explorer

Which eos block explorers has an api endpoint where I can query an account? I want to pull in account json data into my javascript application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(almost) all of them. You can have a look here. https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/

There is also a site specifically providing these services for free (as of time writing)
https://dfuse.io/

Though you should notice that if your application demands fast response, maybe your best option is to run your own node.
Cheers